# Question about primes of the form $n^2+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is the question of existance of infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$ equivalent to existance of infinetely many twin primes in ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

By twin prime Gaussian integers I mean prime ones with smallest possible difference (i.e. $2i$ or $2$).

Note that if $n^2+1$ is prime then $(n+i)(n-i)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, so from the fact that $\overline{n+i} = n - i$ we can get that both $n+i$ and $n-i$ are prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

**EDIT:** From the comments below I think it would be better to reformulate my question to

> Which natural conjecture about Gaussian primes imply "$n^2+1$" conjecture?

Comment: So you've said already that it would imply that there are infinitely many Twin Primes in $\mathbb{Z[i]}$ which is an open question. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884143/about-the-distribution-of-gaussian-prime-pairs). Then we have the other implication remaining. If there are infinitely many twin primes in the Gaussian integers can we say there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$? 
You might check [this](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/FQ/Scanned/6-5/holben-a.pdf) out for a nice definition of twin primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Comment: Yes, but I am interested in reverse : if there are infinitely many twin primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ then there are infinetely many primes of the form $n^2+1$. Or in other words which conjecture about Gaussian primes entails conjecture about infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$?

Comment: I thought that I might be wrong. And the conjecture about primes of the form $n^2+1$ isn't related to twin prime conjecture in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ but is equivalent to the conjecture about infinitely many Gaussian primes on the line $n+i$ and it is analog of $\textbf{Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions}$ for Gaussian integers.

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for but might be a good lead: [Shanks](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1960-14-070/S0025-5718-1960-0111724-0/S0025-5718-1960-0111724-0.pdf) and more generally if you're looking for a good starting spot for research on [this](https://oeis.org/A077800/a077800.html)

Comment: "By twin prime Gaussian integers I mean prime ones with smallest possible difference (i.e. 2i or 2)." Isn't the smallest possible difference 1+i which has a smaller absolute value than 2 or 2i?

Comment: @MichaelStocker. I am not sure that the OP has worked out exactly everything we need to say call these guys twin primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Neither have I for that matter. I would have thought that $|a-b|=2$ with $a$ and $b$ prime would do the job. But it seems that the definition offered in [this](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/FQ/Scanned/6-5/holben-a.pdf) is a little more intricate than that...